# Uplink & switches - advice needed

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a BT Home Hub which has four Gigabit Ethernet ports (https://www.bt.com/help/broadband/learn-about-the-ports-on-your-bt-hub)

I then have an Ethernet cable running from the home hub to a switch under the stairs, with Cat5 cables coming off this switch to a number of locations.

I have a cable run to the attic, I am going to add a second switch here to run four cables to our detached garage in preparation for adding an office space there. (Although in the attic, it is the easiest route to the garage, and I’ve already got a spare CAT5 cable run from the under stairs switch).

I am upgrading the existing switch under the stairs and I have some questions:

1. Do I connect the Ethernet cable from the BT home hub to an uplink port?
2. As the port from the home hub is gigabit would that provide greater bandwidth coming into the switch?
3. If the new (replacement, under stairs) switch has an uplink port, do I need to connect this to an uplink port on a new switch, or any port?
4. Is there any benefit connecting uplink to uplink on two switches?

The existing switch I have is the Netgear GS308P - which says it is a gigabit switch - so I don’t even know if I need to upgrade it to one with an uplink!

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Do I connect the Ethernet cable from the BT home hub to an uplink port?

If your switch is old enough to have an uplink port – yes. (It's also probably old enough to drink.) Such a port used to have "crossover" wiring so that it could be connected to another switch or router without the need for a crossover cable.

(Recall how the "receive" and "transmit" pairs used to work in 10/100 Mbps Ethernet. If both ports used the same pair for transmit, they'd get nothing. So either the ports needed to have opposite wirings, or a special cable had to be used to achieve the same. Some switches even had a physical button to toggle the port between regular and crossover.)

If the switch is newer – it generally won't have a dedicated uplink port in the first place. Practically all new Ethernet devices (including switches and routers) nowadays support auto-crossover allowing *any* port to be connected to *any* kind of device using straight-through Ethernet cables, so they do not mark any port as "uplink".

This auto-crossover feature is practically mandatory for Gigabit Ethernet, but has been quite widespread even in 100 Mbps "Fast Ethernet" devices. As a result, dedicated "uplink" ports on switches are pretty much an obsolete concept.

(I would still use the last port for the uplink connection just to keep things tidy, though.)

> (2) As the port from the home hub is gigabit would that provide greater bandwidth coming into the switch?

If your switch has all identical gigabit ports then it won't make any difference. 1 Gbps is 1 Gbps no matter which port it goes to.

(Of course, there used to be (probably still are) switches that had just one or two 'gigabit' ports and the rest were just 10/100 ports, due to cost. In this case, it's literally just the fact that it's a 'gigabit' port that matters – not because it was "the uplink port" or anything special like that.)

> (3) If the new (replacement, under stairs) switch has an uplink port, do I need to connect this to an uplink port on a new switch, or any port?

No. The whole idea of "uplink" ports, back when they were still necessary, is that they'd be connected to a *normal* port on another switch.

Basically, in 10/100 Mbps Ethernet, the ports on both ends of the cable had to have *opposite* wiring. For example, you couldn't connect two "computer" ports directly, and you couldn't connect two "switch" ports directly.

So the uplink port on a switch was the opposite of normal ports, in order to allow you to connect two switches... but you *still* couldn't connect two "uplink" ports because they were again of the same type. Instead, the "uplink" port on one switch went into a normal (downlink) port on another.

Again, this is basically obsolete because all Ethernet devices found today will just electronically detect and switch to the correct connection type.

> (4) Is there any benefit connecting uplink to uplink on two switches?

None whatsoever.

> The existing switch I have is the Netgear GS308P - which says it is a gigabit switch - so I don’t even know if I need to upgrade it to one with an uplink!

You don't.